# Google Play Services Leaderboards for cross platform games

Tags: google-play-services, google-play-games

I am working at iOS & android games, and I want to implement a leaderboard system.
What I need to do is add and get scores, exactly what google play services leaderboard does.

The question that I have, is it possible to use the REST api for this purpose and using in the game only with HTTP Requests?

Ex: I want to add a score, I do a POST HTTP Request to some google api url, etc.

In the documentation i found this
https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/clientsetup

TL;DR
Can I use the google play services Rest API only with HTTP Requests, from a cross platform mobile game?

Thanks.